# Formula to calculate a t-distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, t-distribution

I am writing an application that will be dealing with <30 observations in a normal distribution. My understanding is that this point I would need to use t-distribution. The thing is, this is easy enough to look up in a table. However, I need this to be something to calculate it programmatically. I can't seem to find a formula to find the t-distribution score.

How can I build this table so to speak?  I am writing this in PHP.

I should also note that I am by no means a math/stat expert. So if my use of terms/vocabulary seems off just bear with me.

Comment: Formulas are in many places, such as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). The problem is that some of them may require numeric integration or approximation to compute; your ability to do that depends on the application platform. The answer is trivial if you're using `R` or even Excel but is a little involved if you're writing in Assembly language! You need to tell us more about your application and its constraints.

Comment: ugh. you are absolutely right. sorry about that. i am writing this in php. just so you are aware, i can't use the php extension stats.

Comment: You will be hard-pressed to find anyone knowledgeable about statistics working routinely in PHP. You might want to have this question migrated to SO in order to reach out to the programming community there.

Comment: At small d.f. you can compute the t-integrals explicitly via integration by parts (you either get down to 1 or 2 df and they're both straightforward), but this is kind of unwieldy. It's possible to find fast and accurate algorithms for calculating t-integrals, many have been published, but likely not for php, so you'd have to translate. Note that for some purposes (like small tail probabilities), $n=30$ may not be sufficient. e.g. if you look up a two tailed p-value for a t of 2.748 with 30 df you get a little over 1%, but if you use z-tables, it gives less than 0.6% -- quite a difference!

Comment: so originally i didn't post what language i was working with because i was and still am looking for the correct formula to calculate the t-integrals. so yea i figured very few people in here would have worked with php (especially when R is available). my plan was to translate to php in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impression is to use PHP build-in function [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-cdf-t.php). I wonder why you cannot use the PHP stat extension?

If you really cannot use that extension, I suggestion you to generate a table and then use interpolation methods. For example, to get a cumulative distribution function table (CDF) to t-distribution, create a table like this [t-distribution table](http://www.math.unb.ca/~knight/utility/t-table.htm).

Comment: yes. i'm trying to figure out how to generate that table. what is that formula.

Comment: i didn't want to use the ext because it draw up some other issues with my php install but i just bit the bullet and fix them. so i compiled the ext and i'll work with it. the other issue as to why i didnt want to use the ext was because there seems to be some pretty limited docu on it. since the docu is pretty light, i'm not sure what to call to get the right info. with that said, any idea on what function to get t-score? i'll play around some more.

Comment: how exactly do you make that table. that is what i've been trying to do.

Comment: In Excel, use -T.INV(0.01,1) where 0.01 means the one-tail probability and 1 is the degree of freedom.

Comment: In R (a popular statistics software), use qt(p=0.01, df = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)

Comment: again, i'm looking for the formula to do this. i understanding R and Excel have functions to do this but i'm not using either.

Answer (score 2):

**Calculating and Plotting T-distribution**

You can use the following formulas to calculate t-distribution.

$ f(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\,\mathrm{B}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})}\left(1+\frac{t^2}{\nu}\right)^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} $

where:

$t$ = t value,

$\nu$ = degrees of freedom.

$\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\displaystyle\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}$

This is not a complex formula, you have to calculate factorial in the second formula which is usually written as $4!=4\times3\times2\times1$. This only valid if x and y are integers.

Here I approach it in R:

```
t = 10
v = 3
x = 1/2
y = v/2 
B_x_y = (factorial((x-1)) * factorial((y-1)))/ factorial((x+y-1))
# when x and y are positive integers, otherwise we need more complex formula 
# we can just use beta function to derive this 
# B_x_y = beta(x,y)

# t-distribution 
f_t = (1/(sqrt(v)* B_x_y) *(1 + t^2/v)^(-((v+1)/2)))

# all of above can be done simply by using inbuilt R function dt 
# dt(10,3)
```

If you like to plot the distribution where df = 3. You can loop the process:

```
ft1 <- rep(NA, 100) 
tv <- seq(-6, 6, 0.1)

for ( i in 1:length(tv)){
  t = tv[i]
  v = 3
  x = 1/2
  y = v/2 
  B_x_y <- (factorial((x-1)) * factorial((y-1)))/ factorial((x+y-1))
  ft1[i] <- (1/(sqrt(v)* B_x_y) *(1 + t^2/v)^(-((v+1)/2)))
}         

plot(tv, ft1, type = "l", col = "blue", xlab = "t", ylab = "p", 
     main = paste ("t distribution with ", v, " degrees of freedom" )
```

[image]

All of the above process can be simply written as using dt function:

```
plot(tv, dt(tv, 3), col = "blue", type = "l", xlab = "t", ylab = "p")
```

**Creating Table**

For creating table you need cumulative density function.  "The cumulative distribution function (CDF) describes the probability that a real-valued random variable X with a given probability distribution will be found to have a value less than or equal to x".

$ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^t f(u)\,du = \tfrac{1}{2} + t\frac{\Gamma \left( \tfrac{1}{2}(\nu+1) \right)} {\sqrt{\pi\nu}\,\Gamma \left(\tfrac{\nu}{2}\right)} \, {}_2F_1 \left( \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}(\nu+1); \tfrac{3}{2}; -\tfrac{t^2}{\nu} \right) $

${}_2F_1$ is a particular case of the hypergeometric function.

```
# pt(q, df)
# q is quantile
# Say we want 99% probability value (alpha = 0.01) for 3 df (looking table)
qt(0.99, 3)
4.540703
```

Comment: The factorials cannot be used to compute a Beta function except for positive integral arguments. Did you notice that the arguments are not necessarily integers? The method you give will also overflow for relatively small values of the arguments (although you should be OK for low degrees of freedom). Generally, it's a good idea to implement Beta (and Gamma) for arbitrary numbers--at least for positive reals--because t distributions with arbitrary degrees of freedom are used in such common situations as Welch's or Satterthwaite's t-tests.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a software package to calculate this for you.

[R](http://www.r-project.org/) is a standard platform for statistics and is free.

The main functions you would want to look up are `pt`, `qt` (You can get the manual of a function by using '`?function`' in R command line).

There are various wrappers to access R from other programming environments as well as other stats packages.